# large sparse matrix, svd

Tags: java, matrix, svd

I want to calculate SVD , but I didn't find good java library for this. Now, I have data store in hashmap, because matrix didn't fit into memory due to the fact that sizes are about 400 000 X 10 000 and most of them are 0. I tried MTJ, JBLAS, Jama and others but most of them don't support sparse matrices or are too slow. I need this calculation to be done in max 2-3 minutes. Can somebody recommend me something ?
I read also about irbla in R, but it is possible to send my data from java to R, make calculations and send it back to my java program ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem while trying to apply Non-negative Matrix Factorization (NNMF) and Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis to large sparse term-document matrices. I tried Jblas<sup>1</sup> and Jama<sup>2</sup> but I finally used Matlab. And because I was writting the whole app in Java I ended up calling Matlab with Java through the [Matlab Runtime Compiler (MRC)](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/).

What to do:
Matlab has a feature called [Matlab Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/). Use this tool to produce a .jar file which has your matlab code and can then be called by your java program. This .jar needs the MRC to work.

<sup>1</sup>Jblas was much faster than Jama but I had problems and couldn't make it run with jdk for 64bits.
<sup>2</sup> Jama used `doube[][]` and this caused problems with memory.
Maybe the above have changed because I am reffering back to July 2012 and don't have clear image about now.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'll check it. Could you write some java code ? Should I create double [][] matrix to pass it to matlab code , because it is impossible

Comment: At my case I had the term-document matrix stored in .txt files (space delimited). So I called my matlab code, loaded the txt file and did the rest...